# Problems with getting some data of an xml file

Tags: python

My xml file is the next:

```
<cars>
    <car brand='Chevrolet'>
        <in_shipping>
            <color>red</color>
            <place>4</place>
        </in_shipping>
        <in_production>
            <color>blue</color>
            <place>2</place>
        </in_production>
        <stock color='red' place='1'>4</stock>
        <stock color='green' place='2'>1</stock>
        <stock color='blue' place='3'>6</stock>
        <stock color='purple' place='4'>7</stock>
    </car>
    <car brand='Ford'>
        <in_shipping>
            <color>silver</color>
            <place>2</place>
        </in_shipping>
        <in_production>
            <color>black</color>
            <place>1</place>
        </in_production>
        <stock color='green' place='2'>1</stock>
        <stock color='red' place='1'>4</stock>
        <stock color='blue' place='3'>6</stock>
    </car>
</cars>
```

And I would like to get next data in console by printing it in just one line:

```
red 4
blue 2
red 1 4
green 2 1
blue 3 6
purple 4 7
silver 2
black 1
green 2 1
red 1 4
blue 3 6
```

I tried with the next:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def data():
    tree = ET.parse('stack.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i in root:
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                print(k.text,j.attrib['color'], j.attrib['place'], j.text)#Here 'k.text' won't print next to below tag
data()
```

But in console I just get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/riram/Documents/test/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    data()
  File "c:/Users/riram/Documents/test/test.py", line 9, in data
    print(k.text,j.attrib['color'], j.attrib['place'], j.text)
KeyError: 'color'
```

I know part of my error is because `in_shipping` and `in_production` tags don´t have attributes, and other problem is that I don´t know how to separate in `in_shipping` and `in_production` by `color` tag and `place` tag, so `k.text` I think it would print:

```
red
4
blue
2
silver
2
black
1
```

So I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that easily with `beautifulsoup` using `lxml` parser.

- Select the `<car>` tags using `.findAll()` method from `soup`.
- Iterate over each `<car>` tag and

  - Select the `<in_shipping>` and `<in_production>` tags separately and print the text between `<color>` and `<place>`
  - Select the `<stock>` tags and print it's attributes `color`, `price` and the text.

```py
import bs4 as bs

s = '''
<cars>
    <car brand='Chevrolet'>
        <in_shipping>
            <color>red</color>
            <place>4</place>
        </in_shipping>
        <in_production>
            <color>blue</color>
            <place>2</place>
        </in_production>
        <stock color='red' place='1'>4</stock>
        <stock color='green' place='2'>1</stock>
        <stock color='blue' place='3'>6</stock>
        <stock color='purple' place='4'>7</stock>
    </car>
    <car brand='Ford'>
        <in_shipping>
            <color>silver</color>
            <place>2</place>
        </in_shipping>
        <in_production>
            <color>black</color>
            <place>1</place>
        </in_production>
        <stock color='green' place='2'>1</stock>
        <stock color='red' place='1'>4</stock>
        <stock color='blue' place='3'>6</stock>
    </car>
</cars>
'''

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
cars = soup.findAll('car')
for car in cars:
    ins = car.find('in_shipping')
    if ins:
        print(f"{ins.find('color').text.strip()} {ins.find('place').text.strip()}")
    inp = car.find('in_production')
    if inp:
        print(f"{inp.find('color').text.strip()} {inp.find('place').text.strip()}")

    for st in car.findAll('stock'):
        print(f"{st['color']} {st['place']} {st.text.strip()}")
```

```
red 4
blue 2
red 1 4
green 2 1
blue 3 6
purple 4 7
silver 2
black 1
green 2 1
red 1 4
blue 3 6
```

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<cars>
    <car brand='Chevrolet'>
        <in_shipping>
            <color>red</color>
            <place>4</place>
        </in_shipping>
        <in_production>
            <color>blue</color>
            <place>2</place>
        </in_production>
        <stock color='red' place='1'>4</stock>
        <stock color='green' place='2'>1</stock>
        <stock color='blue' place='3'>6</stock>
        <stock color='purple' place='4'>7</stock>
    </car>
    <car brand='Ford'>
        <in_shipping>
            <color>silver</color>
            <place>2</place>
        </in_shipping>
        <in_production>
            <color>black</color>
            <place>1</place>
        </in_production>
        <stock color='green' place='2'>1</stock>
        <stock color='red' place='1'>4</stock>
        <stock color='blue' place='3'>6</stock>
    </car>
</cars>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
cars = root.findall('.//car')
for car in cars:
    in_shipping = car.find('in_shipping')
    in_production = car.find('in_production')
    stock_elements = car.findall('stock')
    print(f'{in_shipping.find("color").text} {in_shipping.find("place").text}')
    print(f'{in_production.find("color").text} {in_production.find("place").text}')
    for stock in stock_elements:
        print(f'{stock.attrib["color"]} {stock.attrib["place"]} {stock.text}')
```

output

```
red 4
blue 2
red 1 4
green 2 1
blue 3 6
purple 4 7
silver 2
black 1
green 2 1
red 1 4
blue 3 6
```